# How do I recursively set the date created attribute to the date modified attribute on NTFS-3G?

Tags: files, date, file-copy, ntfs, ntfs-3g

In my first question: [How do I get the creation date of a file on an NTFS logical volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87265/how-do-i-get-the-creation-date-of-a-file-on-an-ntfs-logical-volume), I asked how to get the "Date created" field in NTFS-3G. Now, that I know I can get the "Date created", I have started adding files onto my NTFS-3G partition and would like to set the "Date created" of each file to its "Date modified" value.

Since this needs to be done on a whole repository of files, I would like to recursively apply it to a single directory on down. If I know how to do this for a single file, I could probably do the recursion myself, but if you want to add that in I would be more than happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system.ntfs_times` extended attribute contains 32 bytes that consist of the btime, mtime, atime, ctime as 64bit integers.

You can list them with for instance:

```
getfattr --only-values -n system.ntfs_times -- "$file" |
  perl -MPOSIX -0777 -ne 'print ctime $_/10000000-11644473600 for unpack("Q4",$_)'
```

So you can just copy the second integer to the first with something like:

```
getfattr -n system.ntfs_times -e hex -- "$file" |
  sed '2s/0x.\{16\}\(.\{16\}\)/0x\1\1/' |
  setfattr --restore=-
```

Comment: This is awesome. I don't have a Linux box that I could test this one (with easy access to NTFS), but I might be able to add an NTFS partition to one of my current boxes to play around with it.