# Do any archive utilities exist that can preserve the date created file attribute on NTFS-3G?

Tags: files, file-copy, ntfs, zip, ntfs-3g

I tried the `-X` switch on `zip`, but that did not save the date created attribute. I can get it [using this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87265/how-do-i-get-the-creation-date-of-a-file-on-an-ntfs-logical-volume). When a file is added to a zip archive using 7-Zip, it preserves the date created and date accessed attributes. I would like to do the same on Linux and then extract my files on Windows, while preserving the date created.

Comment: If possible, change your filesystem for backup system

Comment: Have you tried using 7-zip? It is not a Windows-specific program. Also, does your filesystem keep a record of the date created? Many do not.

Comment: It's typically called 7z in unix.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd expect anything from the `-X` switch either. I think it's to include/exclude the extended attributes related to ACL.

Comment: @slm also, as far as I know, ext filesystems do not store the creation date, only the modification data so this might not be possible if the files are coming from ext.

Comment: @terdon Ah, I assumed that `zip` was `7z`, I'll go install it and try again. I added a link to my first question where I can now get the date created for NTFS-3G and it does work. The files are definitely on an NTFS-3G partition (shows them as root:root with 777 permissions).

Comment: OK, since you said "... on Linux and extract on Windows" I thought you were copying from a Linux filesystem to NTFS.

Comment: You might want to try using bsdtar instead of the usual GNU tar. It can save extended file attributes, and it does save a creation time when used with *BSD filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

You could safe the times in a separate file:

```
(cd /path/to/ntfs/fs && getfattr -n system.ntfs_times -R .) > times
```

And to restore the times:

```
(cd /path/to/ntfs/fs && setfattr --recover=-) < times
```

Comment: Sounds perfect! I'll try it next chance I get.