# How can get the creation date of a file?

Tags: files, timestamps, stat

I want to find out the creation date of a particular file on a Linux system. Not the modification date or access date, the creation date.

I have tried with `ls -ltrh` and `stat filename` but neither gives me what I need. What else can I do to get this information?

Comment: Linux doesn't keep track of the creation time since it is not required by POSIX. However, Mac OS X does with the HFS filesystem — look under "birth time" in [`stat(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html).

Comment: Fedora 19 ext4 filesystems do set file creation times. I'm sure there are many more examples. See answer below that uses `stap` to retrieve creation times.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time?lq=1

Comment: @200_success: `stat` still works on the MacOS' APFS; e.g. `stat -f "%m%t%SB %N" ./myfile.txt | cut -f2-`

Answer (score 118):

`stat -c '%w' file` on filesystems that store creation time.

Note that on Linux this requires [`coreutils` 8.31, `glibc` 2.28 and kernel version 4.11 or newer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119699/43779).

The POSIX standard only defines [three distinct timestamps](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_09) to be stored for each file: the time of last data access, the time of last data modification, and the time the file status last changed.

Modern Linux filesystems, such as ext4, Btrfs, XFS ([v5 and later](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/xfs/xfs-documentation.git/tree/design/XFS_Filesystem_Structure/ondisk_inode.asciidoc)) and JFS, [do store the file creation time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time) (aka birth time), but use different names for the field in question (`crtime` in ext4/XFS, `otime` in Btrfs and JFS). Linux provides the [statx(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) system call interface for retrieving the file birth time for filesystems that support it since kernel version 4.11. (So even when creation time support has been added to a filesystem, some deployed kernels have not immediately supported it, even after adding nominal support for that filesystem version, [e.g., XFS v5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/595769).)

As [Craig Sanders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91201/43779) and [Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91205/43779) pointed out, `stat` does support the `%w` and `%W` format specifiers for displaying the file birth time (in human readable format and in seconds since Epoch respectively) prior to `coreutils` version 8.31. However, `coreutils` `stat` uses the `statx()` system call where available to retrieve the birth time only since version 8.31.
Prior to `coreutils` version 8.31 `stat` accessed the birth time via the `get_stat_birthtime()` provided by gnulib (in `lib/stat-time.h`), which gets the birth time from the `st_birthtime` and `st_birthtimensec` fields of the `stat` structure returned by the `stat()` system call. While for instance BSD systems (and in extension OS X) provide `st_birthtime` via `stat`, Linux does not. This is why  `stat -c '%w' file` outputs `-` (indicating an unknown creation time) on Linux prior to `coreutils` 8.31 even for filesystems which do store the creation time internally.

As [Stephane Chazelas  points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87275), some filesystems, such as ntfs-3g, expose the file creation times via extended file attributes.

Comment: You can use `stap` to create your own kernel API.  See example in answer here.

Comment: POSIX is actually wrong on this. mtime used to be both mtime and ctime, and ctime was creation time in orginal unix. see https://blog.plover.com/Unix/ctime.html

Answer (score 30):

TLDR;  Use `stap` (["SystemTap"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap)) to create your own kernel API.  Demo of ext4 creation time extraction below.

You can extract the ext4 creation times on Fedora 19 systems.  Here's mine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux steelers.net 3.11.1-200.fc19.i686.PAE #1 SMP Sat Sep 14 15:20:42 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

It's clear that the inodes on my ext4 partitions have the creation time.  Here's a shell script that determines the inode associated with a filename and then augments the `stat` output with the creation time by using `stap` ("systemtap").

NB:  This is just a demo and **hugely** inefficient since a kernel module is created, loaded, and unloaded for every execution.  This is also probably very fragile as no error checking is performed.  A proper kernel API would be preferable, but this script could be made much more efficient and read the creation times of multiple files/inodes.

[contents of stap_stat.sh]

```
#/bin/sh

my_inode_str=$(stat --printf="%i" $1)

stap - << end_of_stap_script
global my_offsetof
probe begin {
  system("stat $1");
  my_offsetof = &@cast(0,"struct ext4_inode_info")->vfs_inode;
}
probe kernel.function("ext4_getattr@fs/ext4/inode.c") {
  probe_inode=\$dentry->d_inode;
  if (@cast(probe_inode, "struct inode")->i_ino == $my_inode_str) {
    my_i_crtime = &@cast(probe_inode - my_offsetof,"struct ext4_inode_info")->i_crtime;
    printf("CrTime: %s GMT\n", ctime(@cast(my_i_crtime, "timespec")->tv_sec));
    printf("CrTime (nsecs): %d\n", @cast(my_i_crtime, "timespec")->tv_nsec);
    exit();
  }
}
end_of_stap_script
```

Here's a demo:

```
$ ll testfile
ls: cannot access testfile: No such file or directory
$ touch testfile
$ ./stap_stat.sh testfile
  File: ‘testfile’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 4850501     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/    Rick)   Gid: ( 1001/    Rick)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2013-09-28 06:17:04.221441084 -0400
Modify: 2013-09-28 06:17:04.221441084 -0400
Change: 2013-09-28 06:17:04.221441084 -0400
 Birth: -
CrTime: Sat Sep 28 10:17:04 2013 GMT
CrTime (nsecs): 220441085
$ ll testfile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Rick Rick 0 Sep 28 06:17 testfile
$ cat - >> testfile 
Now is the time ...
$ ll testfile 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Rick Rick 20 Sep 28 06:18 testfile
$ ./stap_stat.sh testfile
  File: ‘testfile’
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 4850501     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/    Rick)   Gid: ( 1001/    Rick)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2013-09-28 06:17:04.221441084 -0400
Modify: 2013-09-28 06:18:33.684374740 -0400
Change: 2013-09-28 06:18:33.684374740 -0400
 Birth: -
CrTime: Sat Sep 28 10:17:04 2013 GMT
CrTime (nsecs): 220441085
$ cat testfile 
Now is the time ...
$ ./stap_stat.sh testfile
  File: ‘testfile’
  Size: 20          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 4850501     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/    Rick)   Gid: ( 1001/    Rick)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2013-09-28 06:19:12.199349463 -0400
Modify: 2013-09-28 06:18:33.684374740 -0400
Change: 2013-09-28 06:18:33.684374740 -0400
 Birth: -
CrTime: Sat Sep 28 10:17:04 2013 GMT
CrTime (nsecs): 220441085
$ mv testfile testfile2
$ ./stap_stat.sh testfile2 
  File: ‘testfile2’
  Size: 20          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 4850501     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/    Rick)   Gid: ( 1001/    Rick)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2013-09-28 06:19:12.199349463 -0400
Modify: 2013-09-28 06:18:33.684374740 -0400
Change: 2013-09-28 06:20:45.870295668 -0400
 Birth: -
CrTime: Sat Sep 28 10:17:04 2013 GMT
CrTime (nsecs): 220441085
$
```

Comment: Ok, that is just cool. +1 for using stap, monkey patching the linux kernel, awesome.

Comment: @ChrisMagnuson: [`debugfs + stat`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file#comment524499_155540) allow to get `crtime` without monkey patching the kernel.

Answer (score 22):

In theory, with GNU stat you could use `stat -c '%w'` or `%W` to get a file's creation date (aka birthtime).

In practice, most filesystems do not record that information and the linux kernel does not provide any way of accessing it.

The closest you can get is the file's ctime, which is *not* the creation time, it is the time that the file's metadata was last changed.

Linux Weekly News had an interesting article about this a few years back - [File creation times](http://lwn.net/Articles/397442/).

Comment: Update: Since Linux 4.11, it is actually possible to retrieve crtime (on filesystems that support it).

Answer (score 20):

In `ext4` it is possible; because `ext4` file-system stores the file creation time. But still, you will find that the `stat` command is unable to show the date, because I think the kernel is not having any APIs for this.

Anyway, the file birth time is stored in `ext4` and you can find it out, although not by a direct method, but by using `debugfs`

> sudo debugfs -R "stat /ABSOLUTE/PATH"  /dev/sdxX  | grep crtime

Comment: as a bash function: [`xstat filename`](http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/)

Comment: If `/dev/sdxX` is mounted in `/some/path` and the file is `/some/path/some/file`, the path to be specified is only `some/file`: its path must be referred not to the filesystem root, but to the mountpoint. Otherwise, the file won't be found.

Answer (score 12):

In OS X you can use `ls -lU`, `stat -f%B`, `GetFileInfo -d`, or `mdls -n kMDItemFSCreationDate`:

```
$ ls -lU
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 lauri  staff  0 Apr 25 03:58 a
$ stat -f%B a
1398387538
$ stat -f%SB -t %Y%m%d%H%M a
201404250358
$ GetFileInfo -d a
04/25/2014 03:58:58
$ mdls -n kMDItemFSCreationDate a
kMDItemFSCreationDate = 2014-04-25 00:58:58 +0000
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks! Evidently there's more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

```
stat --printf='%w' yourfile   #human readable

stat --printf='%W' yourfile   #seconds from Epoch , 0 if unknown
```

Difference between `FreeBSD` and `GNU\Linux` on `stat command`:

If you call `stat` command in `GNU\Linux` it invokes the `-x`  option, but in FreeBSD, you yourself should invoke the `-x` option.

See also [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562/16640)

**Notes:** `--printf` is very useful in `scripting`....!

Comment: // , Tried this on a CEntOS 6 machine, and all I got were question marks: $ stat --printf='%w' ~/dump.rdb        ? Maybe my file system doesn't support stat with %w.

Comment: unfortunately, HFS doesn't support ctime.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

```
# the last arg is the device to scan in.
debugfs -R 'stat /home/renich/somefile' /dev/sda1
```

BTW, this works on ext4 only. I haven't found a solution for BtrFS... yet ;)

Comment: That's pretty much what _beginer_'s answer says... isn't it ?

Comment: whoops, you're right @don_crissti

Answer (score 0):

I am using ubuntu, and most files are under ext4 file system, so we can ignore cases in other ones, like Btrfs, XFS (v5 and later) and JFS.

The standard ext4 Linux file system  allocates space for a file-creation timestamp in its internal file system structures, but this ***hasn’t been implemented*** yet  (I tried on Ubuntu 20.04)

Use this as an **alternative**:

```
stat --format='%z' {{YOUR_file}}
```

%z:  time of last **status change**, human-readable. (aka ctime)
ctime: **Changed timestamps**, aren’t referring to changes made to the contents of a file. Rather, it’s the time at which the **metadata** related to the file was changed. File permission changes, for example, will update the changed timestamp.

atime v.s ctime v.s. mtime:
https://www.howtogeek.com/517098/linux-file-timestamps-explained-atime-mtime-and-ctime/

more about metadate of a file:
[https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/l21.pdf](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Esmb/classes/s06-4118/l21.pdf)

Comment: [It has been implemented.](https://askubuntu.com/a/980750/158442) Use 20.10 or newer and `stat` should work OOTB for showing creation time on ext4.