# How to get new created (not change or modified), & removed files in last 24 hours

Tags: files

I want to write one script where I need the below function :

1. List all the files which are created in last 24 hours.
   If I give the `find` command with `ctime` option then it list all files which are change (permission & woner)

   `find . -ctime -1`

   But I need the list of new files which are created not modified or change in last 24 hours.
2. List all the files which are removed in last 24 hours.
   If I removed any files then how I get those files name.
3. How to get the birth time (Creation time) of a file.
   There is one format in `stat` command which give the birth time of a file

   `%w   Time of file birth, human-readable; - if unknown`

   `%W   Time of file birth, seconds since Epoch; 0 if unknown`

```
abc@123:# stat -c %w tzls.txt
-
abc@123:#
```

But it is not giving any output.
My linux filesystem is ext3.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this on many Linux filesystems because the "created" attribute simply doesn't exist. You might want to read some of these links

- [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time)
- [How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created)
- [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file)

If you really need to find files that have been *created* in the last 24 hours, as distinct from those that have been *created or changed*, you have two choices:

1 Switch to a filesystem that supports creation date, and use a combination of `find` and `stat --format '%w'` to get the list of such files

2 Run `find / -type f` every 24 hours, and compare the current run results with those of the previous run. Something like this could work, run once every 24 hours:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
test -f /tmp/today && mv -f /tmp/today /tmp/yesterday
find / -type f | sort > /tmp/today
test -f /tmp/yesterday && comm -13 /tmp/yesterday /tmp/today
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention Linux (though he referred to GNU stat). FreeBSD/OS/X find have `-Bmin`, `-Btime`, `-Bnewer` to act on birth time.

Comment: On Linux, the creation date (whatever that means) is stored on most modern native file systems, but (with the possible exception of some Suse based systems), there's no kernel API to retrieve it so those `%w` of GNU stat won't work.

Comment: Oops, sorry, he did mention Linux indeed. And birth time was not available in ext3 IIRC. My bad.

Comment: @Stéphane thank you. Wasn't aware that API simply didn't make it available. Am curious about that so will go investigate (for my own understanding).