# How to create a bash script that sees all files in a directory and tells me their size and date of creation?

Tags: bash, files, scripting, ls

I'm trying to write a  bash script that will see all files in a directory, and then tell me each file's size and each of their dates of creation.

Comment: From a shell prompt, start with `man stat`. Note that most filesystems do not store a file's create date.

Comment: @glennjackman they do store last written date.

Comment: Have a look at `ls` and `*` (globs). I.e `ls -l *` or `stat *`

Answer (score 1):

Getting the creation date will be a tough one on a Linux system as it isn't stored.

Related question: 
[How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file)

Use the `ls` command to list files, try the options `-a` and `-s` to list all, and list their sizes. Use the command `man ls` on the command line to read a full description on the `ls` command