# birth/crtime timestamp is recorded on one xfs but not the other xfs filesystem

Tags: fedora, rhel, filesystems, timestamps, xfs

Two different xfs filesystems on two different Fedora.

1. Why one of them records Birth(crtime) in the inode and why the other one doesn't?
2. How to find the configuration/attribute differences between the two filesystems?

#1 XFS v5 (Fedora 30):

```
# stat tea.txt 
File: tea.txt
Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 17477205    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0
Access: 2020-06-29 20:49:05.667633345 +0100
Modify: 2020-06-29 20:49:05.667633345 +0100
Change: 2020-06-29 20:49:05.667633345 +0100
Birth: 2020-06-29 20:49:05.667633345 +0100

xfs_db> version
versionnum [0xb4b5+0x18a] = V5,NLINK,DIRV2,ATTR,ALIGN,LOGV2,EXTFLG,MOREBITS,ATTR2,LAZYSBCOUNT,PROJID32BIT,CRC,FTYPE,FINOBT

# xfs_info /dev/sda1
meta-data=/dev/sda1 isize=512    agcount=5, agsize=1376256 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=0, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=6291456, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2688, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

#2 XFS v5 (Fedora 32):

```
# stat tea2.txt
File: tea2.txt
Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 700h/1792d  Inode: 132         Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0
Access: 2020-06-29 20:59:26.855416418 +0100
Modify: 2020-06-29 20:59:26.855416418 +0100
Change: 2020-06-29 20:59:26.855416418 +0100
Birth: -
        
xfs_db> version
versionnum [0xb4b5+0x18a] = V5,NLINK,DIRV2,ATTR,ALIGN,LOGV2,EXTFLG,MOREBITS,ATTR2,LAZYSBCOUNT,PROJID32BIT,CRC,FTYPE,FINOBT
    
# xfs_info /dev/sda1
meta-data=/dev/sda1              isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=11796480 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=0, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=47185920, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=23040, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the options with which each are mounted (e.g., the output of the `mount` command for the given filesystems?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40093/31256), and oh [so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67895/31256 "How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?") many [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200/31256 "How to find creation date of file?") topics here on [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842384/2303098 "How to get file creation date/time in Bash/Debian?").

Comment: Probably they are running different kernel versions and only one of them adds this info.