# Why does the history command show few commands and the .bash_history file is short even if HISTFILESIZE and HISTSIZE are ridiculously high?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, command-history, session

I've read these two questions and the accepted answers on StackOverflow:

- [Unlimited Bash History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history)
- [bash HISTSIZE vs. HISTFILESIZE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize)

However, I still don't understand why in any `bash` session I can see this

```bsh
$ echo $HISTSIZE 
1000000
$ echo $HISTFILESIZE 
10000000
$ wc -l $HISTFILE
3822 /home/enrico/.bash_history
$ history | wc -l
1914
```

where the last two numbers are just... low! And indeed, the history in which I can search for past commands is that short, which means close to useless.

***And this is not just now that I write the question! Basically `history | wc -l` and `wc -l $HISTFILE` have always been that low since I have memory of this system, which I bought in summer 2020. Probably I've misconfigured something in the early days...?***

If it is of interest, these are the only lines from my `~/.bashrc` that match `hist` case insensitively:

```bsh
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
shopt -s histappend
HISTSIZE=1000000
HISTFILESIZE=10000000
    history -a # this is in a function that is assigned to PROMPT_COMMAND
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -s lithist
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

Other info:

```bsh
$ ls -l .bash_history 
-rw------- 1 enrico enrico 59833 Feb 19 18:57 .bash_history
```

The system in question is mine personal, there's no admin but me (and I'm not knowledgeable for an admin, as you see), and I'm using this system since summer 2020. Nonetheless

```bsh
$ stat -c '%w' .bash_history
2021-02-05 18:53:22.365436127 +0000
```

Comment: Is it a new system? Have you modified the parameters recently? On my
system `echo $HISTFILESIZE` is equal to `wc -l $HISTFILE`

Comment: No, I've been using this system everyday for one year at least :/

Comment: What OS?  Does your `.bash_history` have a creation date?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Archlinux. If [`stat -c '%w' .bash_history`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200/164309) is the way to answer your second question, then I have no idea why it shows `2021-02-05 18:53:22.365436127 +0000`, as I use bash everyday, and not since just 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Something deleted your `.bash_history` file, and it was recreated at that date and time, probably the first time you logged out or otherwise ended a `bash` session after the file was deleted.  [Have you annoyed one of your system administrators lately?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell)  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I've updated the question.

Comment: @phunsoft, what is _its `file mde`_?

Comment: Every one of your `bash` processes is writing to the SAME file. The last one to exit, and flush its buffers wins. See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/80882/25618

Comment: Who owns your .bash_history and what is its```file mode```. (Sorry for the ```file mde``` typo; saw it too late to be able to edit.)

Comment: You have `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth`, which means duplicates are ignored and not saved (and commands starting with a space won't be saved either). Maybe you're just not typing that many _unique_ commands?

Comment: @Kusalananda, it's simply not possible, as the commands in `history` are all marked 2021, but I've been using this system much longer. The history simply is not retained as they should be, according to `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE`. And I'd like to understand why.